# Speeding Up the Numerical Integration of a Product of Numerical Integrands with NIntegrate

Tags: numerical-integration, performance-tuning

I need to solve a set of coupled integral equations within a self-consistent cycle. The final result will be functions, say $A(x)$ and $B(x)$, which are related to each other by some integrals which include also some kernels $K$. The functions $A$ and $B$ and the kernel of the integrals can have sharp cusps in their domain, so a fine grid is needed to resolve the cusps. The grid is 'inhomogeneous' with non-equally distanced points (*i.e.*, highly resolved around the cusped points and less resolved in other regions). The grid has 1000 to 2000 points.

As an instance, the integration would be

$\Sigma(x) = \int_{\varepsilon \in \textit{grid}} \mathrm{d}\varepsilon \, K(\varepsilon, x) \, A(\varepsilon + x) \, B(\varepsilon - 2x)$

I want to perform the numerical integrations with `NIntegrate`, but it is very slow. I have used some additional options in `NIntegrate` to make it faster but it is still not enough, taking up to a few seconds, while in a proper computation, the reasonable duration should be about 10 milliseconds.

The code below is a minimal example of the computation in *Mathematica*; a cusped function is artificially produced, and for simplicity, a uniformly-spaced grid is used:

```
f[x_] := Exp[2/(Abs[x - 1] + 1)]*Exp[-(x/2)^6]; (* artificially produced cusped function; in actual case this will produced numerically *)

xi = -4; (* initial point on the grid *)
xf = +4; (* final point on the grid *)
nPts = 1000; (* nr of points on the grid *)
d = (xf - xi)/(nPts - 1); (* distance between two points on the (uniform) grid *)
data = Table[N[{xi + i*d, f[xi + i*d]}], {i, 0, nPts - 1}]; (* grid points *)
splFunct = Interpolation[data, Method -> {"Spline"}]; (* interpolating spline from the numerically produced data points *)
g[x_] := Piecewise[{{splFunct[x], xi <= x <= xf}}, 0]; (* a function which is equivalent to the spline function on the interval [xi , xf], and vanishes outside *)

intg[x_, c1_, c2_] := g[x]*g[x - c1]*g[x - 2 c2]; (* integrand made from a product of functions with different offsets in the argument, c1 and c2 *)

(* integration for each point on the grid; the result is stored in 'intgResult': *)
Timing[
    intgResult = Table[{data[[i, 1]], 
     NIntegrate[intg[x, data[[i, 1]], data[[i, 1]]], {x, xi, xf}, 
      Method -> {Automatic, "SymbolicProcessing" -> 0}, 
      AccuracyGoal -> 10, MaxPoints -> 2000]},
      {i, 1, Length[data]}];
    ]
```

Currently, the numerical integration takes about 9.5 sec.
Is there any way to produce such results in a few milliseconds (on a PC), as could be done with an equivalent (but much longer) C or Fortran code?

Comment: Just wondering if integration is absolutely necessary here, or if `ListCorrelate` would suffice, given how the accuracy of the integrand between grid points is subject to how closely the interpolation matches the actual function.